# Change dialog title created by status.startResolutionForResult

Tags: android, google-api

The Google API for Android allows me to show a dialog asking users to turn on disabled settings like this [dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skuTa.png) using the Status class. How can I change the title of the dialog?

My other option of implementing a custom dialog won't be possible because there are other settings I'll be asking about (Location Services) which are handled by `startResolutionForResult`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SettingsApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsApi) which you refer to does not allow changing the title of the dialog.

Comment: I would like to confirm one thing. I noticed that Yandex map application changed the title in the mentioned dialog (or they completely repeated the design and implemented 'Ok' button tap to turn on setting immediately, if so, please let me know how I can do this) - http://clip2net.com/s/3GjiEoC . I concluded this because the default text is different, from the Google maps - http://clip2net.com/s/3GjiSCh . Do you have an idea how they (Yandex app) could reach that result ? Any advice would be very helpful for me. Thanks