# Change the message in the Google Location Services dialog

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, google-location-services

I noticed that Yandex maps application change the [title in the Google Location Services dialog](http://clip2net.com/s/3GjiEoC) (or they completely repeated the design and implemented 'Ok' button tap to turn on setting immediately, if so, please let me know how I can do this). I've made this conclusion, because a default text is a **bit** different , [e.g. screenshot from the Google maps application](http://clip2net.com/s/3GjiSCh) .

**Is there way to customize the mentioned dialog?**

I've confused since there is an [answer about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34729417/change-dialog-title-created-by-status-startresolutionforresult/34730757#comment70403507_34730757), but I wanted to be sure that it's impossible, because I found the app which was able to do it.

Comment: Ian Lake is an android authority, if he says it's not possible, it's not possible.

Comment: @TimCastelijns Thanks for information. Even if it's not possible then there should be way to turn on location services pressed "OK" button. And I would like to know how I can do this. Otherwise, It's a magic what Yandex application did, what do you think?

Comment: It is impossible to turn on location services without user interaction and approval

Comment: It's weird. I still can't understand how the phrase "To continue" was changed on "For best results".